# How do I check if a word in a MS Word document is AllCaps?

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I've found a specific word in a MS word Docx document, and would like to return if it's `AllCaps` or not.

I've done this before in vb.net, and I'm not super familiar with C#.

My current try looks like this:

```
    private void IsItCaps(string myWord, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myDoc)
    {
        var find = myDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Find;

        find.ClearFormatting();

        if (find.Font.AllCaps == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myWord + " is AllCaps.");
        }
        else if(find.Font.AllCaps == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myWord + " is not AllCaps.");
        }
    }
```

The `true` and `false` are underlined with the message `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'`

I was confused by this message because I thought AllCaps could be True, False, or whatever that third option is....

**EDIT1**

If I correctly change the single equal to double equal, I get
`Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change = with == as below

```
private void IsItCaps(string myWord, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myDoc)
{
    var find = myDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Find;

    find.ClearFormatting();

    if (find.Font.AllCaps != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myWord + " is AllCaps.");
    }
    else if(find.Font.AllCaps == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myWord + " is not AllCaps.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I posted the question.  But, doesn't solve the issue. ```Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'```

Comment: so you are not getting any messagebox after running the code?

Comment: You should probably change find.Font.AllCaps to find.Font.AllCaps() as it is method.

Comment: Won't compile, the contents of the if, and else if, statements are errors.

Comment: Font.AllCaps can't be used as a method.

Comment: I suspect that instead of true and false, AllCaps should be compared against 1 and 0. Could you try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96519/discussion-between-harsh-and-simmons).